# Find the duplicate numbers in this array,what i'm i doing wrong here?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to find the duplicate numbers in this array, I'm using vectors and want to print the answer, what am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int findDuplicate(vector<int> &arr)
{
    int ans = 0;
    // XOR all elements
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        ans = ans ^ arr[i];
    }

    // XOR [1, n-1]
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        ans = ans ^ i;
    }
    cout << ans;
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> arr = {5, 2, 5, 2, 7, 6, 6};
    findDuplicate(arr);
}
```

Comment: *what i'm i doing wrong here?* -- You chose to write the code using exclusive-or, thus you had a plan in mind.  So where in the program does it diverge from the plan you had?  Use the debugger, and also, use a smaller amount of data.  If it can't work with 3 or 4 numbers, it isn't going to work with seven numbers.

Comment: You can check whether two numbers are the same by checking whether xoring them together produces 0, that doesn't extend to more than 2 numbers though

Comment: @molbdnilo i'm clear with the function i wrote, i'm just confused on how to print my answer while using vector<int> in my function.

Comment: you are already printing the answer? You don't have a new line after it so it might be displayed in an odd place on your console?

Comment: I don't think this XOR algorithm works. Also what do you expect this to do when there is more than one duplicate?

Comment: This seems to be a case of writing code before working out with pencil and paper whether the results will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that are wrong. Let's start with the two easy ones.

You have a cout statement that prints (it turns out) 0. But you don't do an endl, so you don't get a newline.

```
cout << ans << endl;
```

That will actually print a newline, which makes it easier to read.

Second, your method returns a value, which is ignored in main(). You probably want to do this in main:

```
int answer = findDuplicate(arr);
cout << "And the answer is " << answer << endl;
```

Or something like that.

That's all fine and good. That's the easy stuff. But why do you think this XOR code is going to tell you what duplicates their are, especially when there might be multiples of the same value or more than one value with duplicates. Maybe there is some algorithm you know about that none of us do.

But it's printing out 0 when the data clearly has duplicates.

Every duplicate finder I know about that's remotely efficient sorts the data then does a loop through it, keeping track of the last value, and if the next value equals the previous value, you have a duplicate.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
int prevValue = vec[0];
for (int index = 1; index < vec.size(); ++index) {
    int thisValue = vec[index];
    if (thisValue == prevValue) {
        ... Print it
    }
    prevValue = thisValue;
}
```

You can make this smarter if you want to know how many are duplicated, and want to be smart about not printing 6 is duplicated 17 times in a row.